# Nikkor 18-140 G DX VRm - what does the letters mean

Tags: lens, nikon

Just bought a Nikkor 18-140 G DX VRm and am a bit confused regarding the naming.

I understand that VR stands for Vibration Reduction, but what does the inclusion of "m" in VRm mean?

Also, what does the "G" stand for?

Comment: I'm not aware such a "VRm"" lens exists. Link to the purchase page please?

Comment: https://www.ebay.es/itm/C%C3%A1mara-R%C3%A9flex-Nikon-D7100-24-1-megap%C3%ADxeles-V%C3%ADdeos-Full-HD-18-140-G-DX-VRm/303455598298?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Answer (score 0):

`VRm` is just a typo. You can cross reference the annotations on the lens with [the official Nikon Page for your lens (AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-140mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR)](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-dx-nikkor-18-140mm-f%252f3.5-5.6g-ed-vr.html), which lists the following technology attributes (or tags):

`ED` - Extra (low) Dispersion Glass
`VR` - Vibration Reduction
`SWM` - Silent Wave Motor
`IF` - Internal-Focusing
`A-M` - Auto-Manual Mode Support
`SIC` - Super Integrated Coating
`AS` - Aspheric Lens Elements

Not all of these attributes/tags will appear on the lens barrel, but they will all be shown on either the official page for the lens or appear in the User Manual for the lens.

The `G` designation for your lens is not listed as an official Nikon technology attribute on the official lens page, but if you need something of an authoritative definition for it, then [according to this page (How to read your lens barrel)](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/how-to-read-your-nikkor-lens-barrel.html), it just means the aperture on your lens can only be set using a command dial on your Nikon camera body. There is a group of designations that never appear together (`G`, `D`, `AI-s`, and `AI`) which may be regarded as a label of the type of aperture control, though some of these also relate to non-aperture-based functions as well.